# Dynamically generate pages from a list with php

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I need to write a short function to dynamically generate a few very basic pages. At the top of the file I will have an array that lists all of the current pages. Then I need the function to create a page for each item in the array. Here are the items that the page will generate:

```
$appArray = array('testAppOne', 'testAppTwo', 'testAppThree');

$fileName = 'info-'.$appName.'html';
$appLogo = 'path/logo.png';
$appName = appArray[1];
$src = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><img src='".$appLogo."'><h1>'.$appName.'</h1></body></html>'
```

So would I create a foreach statement to iterate through the array and *$fwrite* each file to the specific directory? Or is there a better way to approach this?

I'm aware this would be much easier if we used a database, but we're trying to avoid that for now.

Comment: write files? how about use a data base?

Comment: we're trying to avoid using any database for this

Comment: Because this solution isn't for one site, it's for a large number site and mobile apps which all need to run this page.

Comment: surely it would be a one off process

Comment: With Dragon on this - honestly at first blush this looks like a caching solution, but what would evoke a cache refresh on all of those platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine why you'd want to do this instead of using some dynamic page generation mechanism (i.e. a database), but given the constraints of what you're asking, yes, I think that would be the best way to go.  Something like this:

```
$appArray = array('testAppOne', 'testAppTwo', 'testAppThree');

foreach ($appArray as $app) {
    $fileName = 'info-'.$app.'html';
    $appLogo = 'path/logo.png';
    $src = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><img src="'.$appLogo.'"><h1>'.htmlentities($app).'</h1></body></html>'
    $fh = fopen($fileName, 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $src);
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sqlite3, it's pretty cool for small websites! It's database which can start using immediately.
If you will use it with dibi (http://dibiphp.com/), it will be amazing for you, I am pretty sure!

Create and connect do sqlite code:

```
dibi::connect(array(
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => 'sample.sdb',
));
```

Give it try and you will never regret!